# Pull Information From Active Directory

Tags: microsoft-excel, active-directory

I have two sets of data that I occasionally need to cross reference since neither are complete. I receive a file from HR which includes demographic information for employees (including their email address). I also have access to Outlook contacts being pulled from Active Directory. I sometimes have the need to use a person's email address to find their network "alias" and, up to this point, I have been looking up people on an individual basis.

However, my need to reference this data is increasing and I sometimes have hundreds of people who I need to grab an alias for.

Is there a way to download/query this information from Active Directory so that I can join this data in Excel?

EDIT: I do not have the ability to run a PowerShell script.

[image: Outlook Contact]

Comment: I've found one solution using a third party add-in (https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/3591-outlook-export-global-address-book-to-excel.html), I'm not sure there is easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a suitable solution on Stack Overflow [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405567/outlook-2010-gal-with-excel-vba)
I tweaked the data being compiled and ended up with this as my final sub in Excel.

```
Sub GALExport()

Dim appOL As Object
Dim oGAL As Object
Dim oContact As Object
Dim oUser As Object
Dim arrUsers(1 To 65000, 1 To 5) As String
Dim UserIndex As Long
Dim i As Long

Set appOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oGAL = appOL.GetNameSpace("MAPI").AddressLists("Global Address List").AddressEntries

For i = 1 To oGAL.Count
    Set oContact = oGAL.Item(i)
    If oContact.AddressEntryUserType = 0 Then
        Set oUser = oContact.GetExchangeUser
        If Len(oUser.lastname) > 0 Then
            UserIndex = UserIndex + 1
            arrUsers(UserIndex, 1) = oUser.Name
            arrUsers(UserIndex, 2) = oUser.PrimarySMTPAddress
            arrUsers(UserIndex, 3) = oUser.Alias
            arrUsers(UserIndex, 4) = oUser.JobTitle
            arrUsers(UserIndex, 5) = oUser.Department
        End If
    End If
Next i

appOL.Quit

Range("A1").Value = "Name"
Range("B1").Value = "Email Address"
Range("C1").Value = "Network Alias"
Range("D1").Value = "Job Title"
Range("E1").Value = "Department"

If UserIndex > 0 Then
    Range("A2").Resize(UserIndex, UBound(arrUsers, 2)).Value = arrUsers
End If

Set appOL = Nothing
Set oGAL = Nothing
Set oContact = Nothing
Set oUser = Nothing
Erase arrUsers

End Sub
```